# Wordpress - Adding class to the href in the using wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if its possible to add a class for the current page to the href tag instead of the li tag that wordpress uses by default.

By menu arguments are as follows:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location'    => 'main-menu',
    'container'         => '',
    'menu_class'        => '',
    'menu_id'           => 'nav'
) ); ?>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you want to do this? you can access the A in css using something like this:

```
#nav li.current-menu-item a {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

what exactly do you want to achieve?